# grep filenames from an exclude log

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, grep

I have a problem with my bash script. I want to excluding from processing files that are listed in the exclude.log. After a file is processed it is written in to the exclude log.

```
for I in `ls $1 | grep ./exclude.log -v`

do
    echo "Procesing ...."
    echo $I >> ./exclude.log
done
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I'm stuck, and don't know how to do it in bash.

Comment: @user3018224: From where are you getting list of files to be processed? Is it from `ls` command in current directory?

Comment: I'll get it from directory witch is given as a parameter in to the script. The ls command lists everything in the directory because I want to check if the file is listed in the exclude.log. And the checking doesn't work.

Comment: The -f parameter in the grep syntax did it. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I is not assigned a value.
Also your grep is not right formulated.

You possibly want

```
LIST=$( grep -v -f /path/to/exclude.log * )
for I in $LIST
do
        echo "Procesing ...."
        echo $I >> /path/to/exclude.log
done
```

Make sure you don't have any empty lines in exclude.log

Answer (score 0):

You can use this while loop:

```
while read -r l; do
   echo "$l"; 
done < <(fgrep -v -wf exclude.log <(printf "%s\n" "$1"/*))
```